# How to wait in a for loop for certain amount of time and implement changes to the view?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, imageview, slideshow

I am trying to create a simple slide show. I have NSArray of pictures. I have a for loop and I am trying to show each picture in the for loop for 3 seconds and then show another picture. The problem is that, view appear with no image. It goes inside for loop and wait for 3 seconds but imageView is not changing. After finishing for loop last image will be appear on the view. Following is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.condition = YES;  //condition is boolean
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.condition)
    {

        /*Show slide show*/
        //Here I get data from core data and save them to an array

        for(Pictures *pic in items)
        {
            NSLog(@"LOOP");
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:pic.image];
            sleep(3);

        }
        self.condition = NO;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Every 3 seconds it prints one line but image is not changing inside for loop.

```
2014-10-06 15:05:38.163 JourneyTracker[2471:83227] LOOP
2014-10-06 15:05:41.164 JourneyTracker[2471:83227] LOOP
2014-10-06 15:05:44.166 JourneyTracker[2471:83227] LOOP
2014-10-06 15:05:47.168 JourneyTracker[2471:83227] LOOP
```

Definition of **imageView**:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

I have change it to strong but did not effect anyhting.

**Edit2:**
Thanks a lot rebello95. I have added your code with little changes as following.

```
-(void)showNextSlide {


    NSLog(@"ITEMS ==  %d",items.count);
    NSLog(@"self.slideIdx ==  %d",self.slideIdx);
    if (self.slideIdx == items.count) {
        return;
    }

    //Update the image and call this again after 3 seconds

    Pictures *pic = items[self.slideIdx];

    NSLog(@"descript ==  %@",pic.descript);

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:pic.image];
    NSLog(@"hereee111");
    [self performSelector:@selector(showNextSlide) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
    NSLog(@"hereee222");

    pic=nil;

    //Increment the value
    self.slideIdx++;
}
```

Now the problem is for first interval it works perfect but for second image it returns null value! Here is output

```
2014-10-06 15:52:51.548 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] ITEMS ==  4
2014-10-06 15:52:51.549 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] self.slideIdx ==  0
2014-10-06 15:52:51.549 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] descript ==  info1
2014-10-06 15:52:51.549 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee111
2014-10-06 15:52:51.549 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee222
2014-10-06 15:52:54.550 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] ITEMS ==  4
2014-10-06 15:52:54.550 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] self.slideIdx ==  1
2014-10-06 15:52:54.550 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] descript ==  (null)
2014-10-06 15:52:54.550 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee111
2014-10-06 15:52:54.551 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee222
2014-10-06 15:52:57.552 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] ITEMS ==  4
2014-10-06 15:52:57.552 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] self.slideIdx ==  2
2014-10-06 15:52:57.552 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] descript ==  (null)
2014-10-06 15:52:57.552 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee111
2014-10-06 15:52:57.552 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee222
2014-10-06 15:53:00.554 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] ITEMS ==  4
2014-10-06 15:53:00.554 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] self.slideIdx ==  3
2014-10-06 15:53:00.554 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] descript ==  (null)
2014-10-06 15:53:00.554 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee111
2014-10-06 15:53:00.554 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] hereee222
2014-10-06 15:53:03.555 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] ITEMS ==  4
2014-10-06 15:53:03.556 JourneyTracker[2945:104251] self.slideIdx ==  4
```

Comment: Keep your `imageView` as `weak`, `IBOutlet`s do not need to be `strong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ***never*** sleep the main thread. It will block all user interaction and UI updates.

I'd recommend implementing a function that calls itself every 3 seconds and shows the next slide.

Create an `int` property `slideIdx` and use something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.condition)
    {
        //Get slide data

        self.slideIdx = 0;
        [self showNextSlide];
        self.condition = NO;
    }
}

-(void)showNextSlide {

    //Stop the slideshow if there aren't any more slides (you could just reset it to 0 if you want)
    if (self.slideIdx == items.count - 1) {
        return;
    }

    //Update the image and call this again after 3 seconds
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[(Pictures *)items[self.slideIdx] pic]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showNextSlide) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

    //Increment the value
    self.slideIdx++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have added your code but there is something wrong and as a newbie can not find solution. I have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: @HilaAfshar, nice catch on a incrementing the index too soon. However, you need to check to see if `self.slideIdx == items.count - 1` instead of what we previously had since you moved the increment to after. Please see my update (especially the first line of code in the `showNextSlide` function). I'm assuming you were getting some sort of out of bounds exception?

Comment: @HilaAfshar I just read the rest of your edit. Try explicitly logging the `descript` of each picture when you load them and see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was not able to fix it in this way so everytimr it comes to showNextSlide I read data from core data and it works fine.

Comment: @HilaAfshar That works too I suppose, although it's going to be slower. The best thing would be to try to figure out why your `descript` values are `null`.

Comment: Actually It was not null so I was able to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `NSTimer` that repeats on a 3 second interval. When it fires, call a method to change the photos.